# Potential of vs potential to

Tags: prepositions

Do I say

> potential to reduce criminality

or

> potential of reducing criminality

If both, which is more appropriate when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Potential* is used with either ***to*** or ***for*** to refer to the event or action that may happen:

> *the crane operator's clear view reduces the potential for accidents*
>
> *pesticides with the potential to cause cancer.*

Use **of** to refer to the object having the potential:

> *the potentials of the technology were never wholly controllable.*

<sup>Examples from New Oxford American Dictionary</sup>